# Learning Java, why didn't I get overlap of some threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried the following code:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


    public class Main {
        static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(t1).start();
        new Thread(t2).start();
        new Thread(t3).start();
        new Thread(t4).start();
        new Thread(t5).start();
        new Thread(t6).start();
    }

    private static void countMe(String name){
        i++;
        System.out.println("Current Counter is: " + i + ", updated by: " + name);
    }

    private static Runnable t1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                    countMe("t1");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){}

        }
    };

    private static Runnable t2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                    countMe("t2");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){}
       }
    };
        private static Runnable t3 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                    countMe("t3");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){}
       }
    };
        private static Runnable t4 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                    countMe("t4");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){}
       }
    };
        private static Runnable t5 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                    countMe("t5");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){}
       }
    };
        private static Runnable t6 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                    countMe("t6");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){}
       }
    };
}
```

and on ideone got the output:

`Current Counter is: 1, updated by: t1
Current Counter is: 2, updated by: t1
Current Counter is: 3, updated by: t2
Current Counter is: 4, updated by: t2
Current Counter is: 5, updated by: t3
Current Counter is: 6, updated by: t3
Current Counter is: 7, updated by: t4
Current Counter is: 8, updated by: t4
Current Counter is: 9, updated by: t5
Current Counter is: 10, updated by: t5
Current Counter is: 11, updated by: t6
Current Counter is: 12, updated by: t6`

It seemed everything was going in a linear fashion that is the threads called the function countMe one by one, in the order I created them. Doesn't multiple threads means they may come out of order. What am i missing here? Is it the case that the machine on which I am running(I tried on ideone.com) is configured in such a way that it runs the threads in order they are created?

Comment: The threads may simply be too short. Either make the loops longer or put a `Thread.yield()` call in the loop before calling `countMe()`.

Comment: *May* != *guarantee* (or even make it likely).

Comment: As an aside, you can make your code nicer by creating a single named class that implements `Runnable` and takes a name (`"t1"`, `"t2"` and so on) as a constructor argument.

Comment: Add a `CyclicBarrier` to the code.

Comment: coountMe() is an insignificant amount of code surrounding a printf library call that then makes API calls to output data to stdout within an internal lock.  You have little hope of seeing anything except serialized behaviour.

Comment: Increase the loop size and remove the print.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen but then how would I know they overlapped?

Comment: @biziclop I tried to have a basic understanding, optimizations are the secondary step

Comment: @biziclop you check that i is 12 at the end. To do that you need to add all your threads to an array before they are started and then join on all the threads to wait until they complete.

Answer (score 9):

Thread creation is expensive. What likely happens is that by the time you're done launching thread 2, thread 1 is already finished. When thread 3 starts doing its thing, thread 2 has already finished. And so on.

Insert a six-party [cyclic barrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) at the start of the thread function and see them [race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (possibly even losing some `i` increments since `i++` is not guaranteed to be atomic).

If that's not enough to reliably trigger a race, make the threads do more work.

Comment: Even then, biased locking will favour one thread over another.

Comment: Can disable biased locking on Hotspot with -XX:-UseBiasedLocking

Answer (score 2):

Threads take time to start.  They can take milli-seconds or hundreds of micro-seconds. If that doesn't sound long, consider your CPU can perform a million instructions in that time. i.e. your loops finish before the next thread has a chance to start.

A simple way to see this is to a) have a longer loop like 10+, and b) add a delay like Thread.sleep(1000); and you can see the threads running at the same time.

I also suggest you use an AtomicInteger instead of `int` as `i++` is not thread safe.

Comment: Good answer, but it seems to me the OP was actively trying to make it race.